# Dijkstra’s algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra

When reading about the Dijkstra’s algorithm, I found that you should implement a min heap. I tried implementing a min heap and the algorithm worked, but it also worked when I did not use min heap functions and instead just popped off the vertex at index 0.

I am confused why we need to always choose the vertex with the min distance to explore next when we are going to explore all the vertices in the heap anyway.

For example:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush
from math import inf

graph = {
        'A': [('B', 10), ('C', 3)],
        'C': [('D', 2)],
        'D': [('E', 10)],
        'E': [('A', 7)],
        'B': [('C', 3), ('D', 2)]
    }


def dijkstras(graph, start):
  distances = {}
  
  for vertex in graph:
    distances[vertex] = inf
    
  distances[start] = 0
  vertices_to_explore = [(0, start)]
  while vertices_to_explore:
    current_distance, current_vertex = heappop(vertices_to_explore) # this piece of code
    #current_distance, current_vertex = vertices_to_explore.pop(0) # vs. this piece of code
    for neighbor, edge_weight in graph[current_vertex]:
      new_distance = current_distance + edge_weight
      
      if new_distance < distances[neighbor]:
        distances[neighbor] = new_distance
        heappush(vertices_to_explore, (new_distance, neighbor))
        
  return distances
        
distances_from_d = dijkstras(graph, 'D')
print("\n\nShortest Distances: {0}".format(distances_from_d))
```

Why use heappop when pop(0) works the same... is it because of run time? If so why does it run faster?

Thanks

Comment: Runtime is measurable with a compiler and perhaps something you should measure. If they differentiate in time then they really don't work the same. They may have the same result, but I bet you one specializes in heaps while the other works with lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the algorithm works with `vertices_to_explore.pop(0)` is pure luck. In a min-heap, the smallest entry is always at position zero. Hence, if `vertices_to_explore` is a proper heap, the returned element is the same, no matther if you are using `pop(0)` or `heappop`.

The important thing is what happens after that. `heappop` will maintain the heap property. `pop(0)` will not do that. Your graph (and therefore the heap) is small enough that the actions on the heap will be pretty much the same for both methods. But as soon as your graph grows, the non-heapiness of your heap will break the algorithm and the `pop(0)` variant will return wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

We use min-heap and take the vertex with the minimal distance at each step as the Dijkstra algorithm works in a greedy manner; there is no shorter path than the path from the closest vertex at the current step. This is true due to the fact that all distances are positive.

The fact that in the code above regular unsorted list's `pop(0)` worked the same as heap's `heappop()` has to do with a coincidence on the graph given as an input (and not with the algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

The way we implement minheaps the smallest items will be closer to index 0 by probability.. This means that popping at index zero will probably be close to the minimum for small input sets, idk if heap push reheapifies the list, but without heappop it is not going to give you any guarantee and it is certainly no longer dijkstras algorithm. (it might not even be guaranteed to work properly, but this is speculation until I have time to verify this).

It might be faster because the pop at zero can be done in O(1) time (maybe amortised depending on implementation) while the heappop only guarantees O(log N). For very large graphs however, the heappop will likely give you a better chance of finding a shortest path faster (and a correctness guarantee) , thus terminating the algorithm after examining a smaller fraction of the total number of vertices than otherwise. Because while examining ALL the vertices and edges is indeed the worst case, the best case is much better.